# Embed activity inside jetpack composable

Tags: android, android-activity, android-jetpack-compose

Can we embed activity inside composable, so for example, when navigate to that composable its shows the activity content inside it(and not just start activity outside the composable),
That what i succeed so far, but its just show the activity and not embed it

```
@Composable
fun MyContent() {
  val context = LocalContext.current
  val intent = Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java)
  context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

The activity

```
class WebViews : ComponentActivity() {


  var webView: WebView? = null
  private var mUploadMessage: ValueCallback<Uri>? = null
  var uploadMessage: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>? = null
  val REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100
  private val FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1

  var url = "http://example.com"


  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_views)
    webView = findViewById<View>(R.id.webView) as WebView
    webView!!.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView!!.loadUrl(url)
    webView!!.webViewClient = xWebViewClient()
    webView!!.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
      // For 3.0+ Devices (Start)
      // onActivityResult attached before constructor
      protected fun openFileChooser(
        uploadMsg: ValueCallback<Uri>?, acceptType: String?
      ) {
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg
        val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        i.type = "image/*"
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
      }

      // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
      override fun onShowFileChooser(
        mWebView: WebView?,
        filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?,
        fileChooserParams: WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams
      ): Boolean {
        if (uploadMessage != null) {
          uploadMessage!!.onReceiveValue(null)
          uploadMessage = null
        }
        uploadMessage = filePathCallback
        var intent: Intent? = null
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
          intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent()
        }
        try {
          startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
          uploadMessage = null
          return false
        }
        return true
      }

      //For Android 4.1 only
      protected fun openFileChooser(
        uploadMsg: ValueCallback<Uri>?,
        acceptType: String?,
        capture: String?
      ) {
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
      }

      protected fun openFileChooser(uploadMsg: ValueCallback<Uri>?) {
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg
        val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        i.type = "image/*"
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
      }
    }
  }

  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE) {
        if (uploadMessage == null) return
        uploadMessage!!.onReceiveValue(
          WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(
            resultCode,
            intent
          )
        )
        uploadMessage = null
      }
    } else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
      if (null == mUploadMessage) return
      // Use MainActivity.RESULT_OK if you're implementing WebView inside Fragment
      // Use RESULT_OK only if you're implementing WebView inside an Activity
//      val result: Uri? =
//        if (intent == null || resultCode != WebViews.RESULT_OK) null else intent.data
//      mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result)
      mUploadMessage = null
    }
  }


  private class xWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String?): Boolean {
      if (url != null) {
        view.loadUrl(url)
      }
      return true
    }
  }    
}
```

Is there a way to make it work as composable?
Thanks

Comment: why you want to embeed the Activity to the composable ? It breaks all the purpose of a composable

Comment: Because webview doesn't support form file input field, so there is workaround with activity to make it work. But then i want to make it feel part of the app and not just starting activity

Answer (score 1):

> Can we embed activity inside composable

Not really.

If the activity you are trying to start is from some third-party app, or is yours but is not written in Compose UI, the best that you can do is try [activity embedding](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/activity-embedding) on Android 12L and higher.

If the activity that you are trying to start is your own, and it itself is built in Compose UI, you could get rid of that activity and navigate to its composable.

Comment: Its a AppCompatActivity

Comment: @chkml: That does not really change the situation, though I did clarify my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reference the activity through an extenstion function:

```
inline fun <reified Activity : ComponentActivity> Context.getActivity(): Activity? {
    return when (this) {
        is Activity -> this
        else -> {
            var context = this
            while (context is ContextWrapper) {
                context = context.baseContext
                if (context is Activity) return context
            }
            null
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Composable
fun YourComposable() {

    val activity = LocalContext.current.getActivity<MainActivity>()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need to embed the activity content inside composable

Comment: Maybe an AndroidView?  Do you have a composable function in your activity?  I'm not understanding

Comment: I've added the activity to main question, maybe there is a way to make it composable instead of activity?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/webview-in-android-using-jetpack-compose/

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way of approaching your solution is just to hoist the open of the webview outside your composable

Example

```
class MainActivity() {
  setContent {
           YourComposable(param1, param2) { 
            openWebViewCallBack
          }
   }
}


@Composable
fun YourComposable(param1:Int, param2:String, onWebViewOpen: (url:String) -> Unit) { ... }
```